# Display numerical solution of PDE as a movie in Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, matlab

> Investigate numerically whether the FCTS scheme
>   $$
> u_k^{n+1} = u_k^n - \frac{a\Delta t}{2\Delta x} \left( u_{k+1}^n - u_{k-1}^n\right) + \frac{\nu\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} \left( u_{k+1}^n - 2 u_k^n + u_{k-1}^n\right)
> $$
>   can be used for the advection-diffusion equation $v_t + av_x = \nu v_{xx}$. Use a sharp Gaussian-like initial condition (see numerical code that tests the advection equation), $a=1$, $x\in (-5,15)$, 500 mesh intervals, $\Delta t = \min (0.75 \Delta x^2/(2\nu), 0.75 \Delta x/a)$, and compute the solution at $t=10$. Does it break if the diffusion coefficient is small?

Im trying to solve this problem and here is my code:

```
clc;
clear;

%%%Variables%%%%%

xmin=-5;
xmax=15;
N=100; %Number of nodes-1
t=0;
tmax=10;
umax=100;
v=0.05;

%%%%%discretise the domain/time%%%%%
dx=(xmax-xmin)/N;
dt= min([0.75*(dx^2/(2*v)) 0.75*dx]);
x = xmin:dx:xmax;

%%%%%Initial Conditions%%%%%%
F = @(x) umax*exp(-x.^2*10.0);
u0 = F(x);

u=u0;
unp1=u;

timesteps = ceil(tmax/dt);

for n=1:timesteps
    for i=2:N
        unp1(i) = u(i) - dt/(2*dx)*(u(i+1)-u(i-1))+(v*dt)/(dx^2)*(u(i+1)-2*u(i)+u(i-1));
    end
    u=unp1;
    t=t+dt;
    plot(x,u)
end
```

My question is, is there way to plot for a movie for difference values of $v$? at tmax? Also, is my code correctly implemently with the scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks correct, but the problem statement specifies `N=500` instead. Here is the desired Matlab code

```
%%%%%Initial Conditions%%%%%%
F = @(x) umax*exp(-x.^2*10.0);
u0 = F(x);

u=u0;
unp1=u;

figure;
hp=plot(x,u);
ht=title(strcat('t = ',num2str(t)));
xlim([xmin xmax]);
ylim([0 umax]);

timesteps = ceil(tmax/dt);

for n=1:timesteps
    for i=2:N
        unp1(i) = u(i) - dt/(2*dx)*(u(i+1)-u(i-1))+(v*dt)/(dx^2)*(u(i+1)-2*u(i)+u(i-1));
    end
    u=unp1;
    t=t+dt;
    set(hp,'YData',u);
    set(ht,'String',strcat('t = ',num2str(t)));
    drawnow;
end
```

with the following output

[image: output]

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I get this: Error: File: problem.m Line: 28 Column: 17
Creating a string using double quotes is not supported.  Use the string function.

Comment: yes, it does now! Is there a way to plot at $t=10$ but with $v$ varying say between 0 and 0.5 as a movie?

Comment: @Neymar Yes. Manually, you can perform the previous simulations with different diffusion coefficients $\nu$, store them in separate vectors (to do so, comment the `clear` command), and plot them on the same figure (e.g., by using `hold on`) to produce multiple plots. Or algorithmically, you can do the same by operating on multiple vectors at the same time.

Comment: thank you very much! Also, here is another unanswered question about the leapfrog scheme. If you have a chance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107106/trying-to-implement-a-numerical-scheme-in-matlab